# AvailableNow Trigger introduced in Spark 3.3.0 doesn't respect maxOffsetsPerTrigger when reading Kafka stream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, triggers, rate-limiting

According to Bartosz Konieczny's very informative waitingforcode.com blog
[https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/what-new-apache-spark-3.3.0-structured-streaming/read ]
I read that it should be possible to read everything available within  a Kafka topic in multiple batches while
limiting the number of records processed in each batch.

Unfortunately, this didn't work as I would have expected when I tested it
via a small code snippet in spark-shell:

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1
```

I wrote code very similar to that which is shown below to try this out
(names of topics and brokers obscured to protect the innocent):

```
    //val topic = "some-topic-with-huge-amounts-of-data"
    //val bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
    //val availableNow: Trigger = Trigger.AvailableNow()

    val startingOffsets = "earliest"
    val kafkaDF =
        spark.readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets)
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
          .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "5")
          .option("subscribe", topic)
          .load()
    val query = kafkaDF.writeStream .trigger(availableNow) .format("console") .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

When I ran the program above I saw numerous batches, which in and of itself is no issue.  The problem was that in each batch I saw like 20 or so records -- exceeding the maxOffsetsPerTrigger that I specified.  I'm wondering if this is a known issue?  Or perhaps I misconfigured something in my code or testing approach?  Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.